# How do you get this theme in windows 7 and vista?

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-vista, themes

[image]

How do you get this theme in Windows 7 and Vista? I was once playing around with the performance settings in vista and got it, but then it went away. I've also seen it in multiple Windows 7 error messages and I saw it in a youtube video (the picture at the link above).

Answer (score 0):

This looks like the Windows Classic theme. Here's how to activate it:

1. Right-click any open area on the Desktop
2. Select Personalize
3. Scroll down to Basic and High Contrast Themes and select the Windows Classic theme

Comment: Thanks for helping but its not identical to the classic theme.